# How to make a outgoingcall by my App with CallKit in Apple proterozoic UI

Tags: objective-c, voip, callkit

I'm actully finish how to receive an incoming call and call the CallKit UI But when i'm trying to  build my voip app into apple proterozoic contact list UI,it failed .Can you give me any advise?I just want like this below:

[image]

Comment: Can you specify exactly what you are asking about? Do you want your app to show up in the menu for the "Call" and/or "Video" buttons at the top? Or do you want there to be a call button on the right of your app's row on that screen?

Comment: thanks for your answer,I want to do show up in the menu for the "Call" and/or "Video" buttons at the top first.Do you know how to do?

Comment: @zm90125 Were you ever able to do this? If so, could you post an answer to your question describing the solution?

Comment: @TomHarrington Actually When I  realized all the process audio and video use callkit ,it came out self . ( ps: Need to follow the apple process : )  )

Comment: @TomHarrington Maybe realized this first in Appdelegate will do some useful for you.                 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your app appear in the menu for the "Message", "Call", and/or "Video" buttons, you need to list the `INSendMessageIntent`, `INStartAudioCallIntent`, and/or `INStartVideoCallIntent` intent types, respectively, in the array for the `NSUserActivityTypes` key in your app's `Info.plist`.

Then in your app delegate, you implement the `-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` (or in Swift, `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`) method to handle the received action.

Comment: Maybe I forget to list NSUserActivityTypes key ,I will try that later and to see what the difference,thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user102008, I have added the NSUserActivityTypes key in  info.plist, still I couldn't able to see the call option in Recents. What may be the issue?

Comment: @RJVKumar: This question was about in the page for each contact, not Recents. Recents doesn't have a "call option" -- if you tap on a row you just repeat the same type of call with that person.